# Linear transformation of trace to determinant and vice versa

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

There is a symmetrical block-matrix:

$M_1=\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\ 0 & B\end{pmatrix}$

$A,B$ - symmetrical matrices

We can find the trace of this matrix $Tr(M_1)$. Can we find a new matrix $M_2$ such that $Tr(M_1)=Det(M_2[A,B])$ ?

That's such an interesting task :))

I found a special case where this is possible:

[image]

But I did not find a more general solution for symmetrical block-matrix of another dimensions.

Comment: the question is a bit too vague. Notice that I can just take $M_2(A,B)$ as the $1\times 1$ matrix with $Tr(M_1)$ inside

Comment: The Null matrix ?

Comment: @Exodd Yes, well, let's impose additional conditions on the dimension of matrices $A$ and $B$. Let's say ... matrix $A$ be an arbitrary symmetric matrix (not necessarily positive definite) of dimension $2x2$, and matrix $B$ - the same, only dimensions of $3x3$.

Comment: @Lelouch null-matrices are excluded from consideration :)

Comment: Assuming I understand the intent, if the goal is for general matrices $A$ and $B$ to appear as blocks in $M_2$ as in the stated $2 \times 2$ example, it's impossible unless $A$ and $B$ are $1 \times 1$, since the trace is linear in the columns and the determinant multilinear in the columns. (For example, if $A$ is $2 \times 2$, the determinant of a scalar multiple $tA$ is $t^2\det A$, not $t\det A$.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, such a transformation is very difficult to find. I tried to find inspiration in asymptotic ways, but they keep the problem of increasing the error as the order of the derivative grows. So they can only be used for derivatives of order no more than 2-3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant_in_relation_to_other_notions